How to limit matrix underbrace?
I'm looking to get an underbrace illustrating the number of columns in a matrix, but I'm noticing the brace extends to the superscript transpose symbol:

\begin{align}
\label{eq:primitive_mask}
A&=
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
1       & 0 \\
0       & 0 \\
\vdots  & \vdots \\
0       & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}^\top
}_{K}
\end{align}

Is there a simple and straightforward way to avoid this?

{\underbrace{…}_{K}}^\top seems good to me. Otherwise we need to play with \mathrlap and possibly some phantoms …

I've tried to move ^\top, but it's no longer vertically aligned with the matrix. Any way to vertically shift it? Because that would be a simple workaround.

You can use nicematrix, but the underbrace wouldn't be counted for the vertical dimension, so you have to adjust it by hand.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{equation}
A=\begin{bNiceMatrix}
1       & 0 \\
0       & 0 \\
\vdots  & \vdots \\
0       & 1 \\
\CodeAfter\UnderBrace[shorten,yshift=0.7ex]{1-1}{4-2}{K}
\end{bNiceMatrix}^{T}
\smash[t]{\vphantom{\begin{matrix} \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \end{matrix}}}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2][1-4]

\end{document}


Don't use align for a single equation/formula.
A possible improvement where you can make the object deeper by a stated amount that you can decide after looking at the result.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\newcommand{\makedeeper}[2]{% #1 = additional depth, #2 = formula
  \raisebox{0pt}[\height][\dimeval{\depth+#1}]{$\displaystyle#2$}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{equation}
\makedeeper{4ex}{
  A=
  \begin{bNiceMatrix}
  1       & 0 \\
  0       & 0 \\[-1ex]
  \vdots  & \vdots \\
  0       & 1 \\
  \CodeAfter\UnderBrace[shorten,yshift=0.7ex]{1-1}{4-2}{\scriptstyle K}
  \end{bNiceMatrix}^{T}
}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2][1-4]

\end{document}



Don't use align for a single equation/formula. any particular reason for that? I've found that it works better with some document templates than the standard equation environment.

@joaocandre To the contrary, it works (much) worse when the line preceding the display is short.

Anedotically, I only noticed it on a couple of templates I've worked on, but it could be just to how those document templates are set up.

This works, but weirdly I seem to be unable to set/reduce fontsize on the underbrace label e.g. ...{\tiny P'} does not work.

@joaocandre You want \scriptstyle K or \scriptscriptstyle K

@joaocandre I added an improved version for adding the necessary vertical space.

This puts the matrix into a savebox, then uses \mathmakebox (mathtools package) to ignore the extra width caused by adding the transpose.
Just using ^\mathrlap{\top} adds a tiny amount of space.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\sbox1{$\displaystyle\begin{bmatrix}
1       & 0 \\
0       & 0 \\
\vdots  & \vdots \\
0       & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$}% get width
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:primitive_mask}
A=
\underbrace{\mathmakebox[\wd1][l]{%
\usebox1^{\top}}%
}_{K}
\end{equation}

\end{document}

